# Cannot generate texture from bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I currently am working on an android app and up until now I used eclipse android emulator for testing it.

Today I have decided to try it on my phone (Xiaomi mi2) but when I lunch it (via usb debugging) I face 2 problems:

1. I have a background picture that the emulator show perfectly but it doesn't appear on my phone - a black background is shown.
2. Maybe this is the problem for the previous one, the LogCat shows some errors:

`03-01 22:18:35.599: E/OpenGLRenderer(1109): Cannot generate texture from bitmap
03-01 22:18:35.629: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1109): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`

Activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="480dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eu_un"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/enter_user_name" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eu_pw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eu_un"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword|textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:text="@string/signup" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/eu_signin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eu_pw"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eu_signin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:text="@string/exit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eu_un);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eu_pw);
    nu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nu);
    eu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eu_signin);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    ma = this;

    nu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newUser();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This occurs when the bitmap for an image is lost due to recycling, or in the case of hardware acceleration (and openGLRenderer), this occurs when the open GL context is lost. What does your code look like?

Comment: the code of the image?

Comment: The code in your Activity.

Comment: Do you also have a `.java` file?

Comment: Yes but it is very long, what we are searching?

Comment: Mostly the `onCreate` method, and any variables it might be using.

Comment: edited again. I tried to remove the background image and it worked without any errors so it is definitely the cause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25387/discussion-between-phil-and-user1692261)

Comment: Do you use the same Android version on the AVD as on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird bug. I did some searching and found some similar posts that seem to suggest it has to do with the device's keyboard settings:

[Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

[Nexus 7 error "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488695/nexus-7-error-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Most of them have a specific phone in the question.

[SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length error whenever an editText becomes empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698264/span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length-error-whenever-an-editt)

There are tons more if you search

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE+spans+cannot+have+a+zero+length&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

I know this doesn't provide quite the answer you were hoping - but ideally it will get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, the spans error is related to my swiftkey keyboard (I removed it from the question). The bitmap error is related to the background image

Comment: @user1692261 I rolled back the question, since you removing that line would invalidate my answer - and people would see this as a bad response.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this bug with emulated device on genymotion API 16+.

The solution to my issue is to substitute gif images with png images.

Thanks to http://www.pedrorainho.eu/eopenglrenderer2268-cannot-generate-texture-from-bitmap/

Answer (score -1):

I meet the same error in my nexus5 with Android L version.
In my case ,i commented two lines to fix it.
(
//        opt.inPurgeable = true;
//        opt.inInputShareable = true;
)
hope useful for you.
good luck!

below is my code:

```html
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
//        opt.inPurgeable = true;
//        opt.inInputShareable = true;
        
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.error_nothing_app);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opt);
        is.close();
        BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```