# Listactivity error with jelly bean running device ( SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length)

Tags: android

I have app start with Splash screen then open listactivity rows, clicking on any row will opens an activity containing a textview, two buttons (one of which opens an infinite gallery, the other opens a custom dialog), and menu items (about, preference, exit).

This app runs perfectly on ginger bread but when tested on a galaxy s3 running jelly bean, it opens normally but when you click on one of the listactivity rows it appears to ignore the click. The log cat on eclipse  shows :

```
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

However, there is no force close (the listactivity scrolls normally and the menu items work fine and ).

**UPDATE:**
I noticed something this application: I created it with eclipse since around one month ago with a name lets  say (`trip`) and today testing (`trip.apk`) on both ginger bread and jelly bean it works perfectly.

But I wanted to change the name from `trip` to `travel` and I did not use **Refactor**. Instead I created a new project with application name  called `travel` but all other things are the same as the previous app `trip` including classes, res, and when tested with jelly bean shows:

```
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

UPDATE 3 :

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM :

i added this line to all TextViews in my app which is :

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

and that line lead to rows ignore the click ,

so i removed it and now both old and new app work fine with both API .

**UPDATE 4:**

the above phrases related to old issue and already solved ,

**THE QUESTION NOW IS :**

my application work perfectly with all APIs but when tested with:

galaxy S3 running jelly bean work perfectly also ,

**but in eclipse log cat show error :**

```
 SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero  length
```

**without affect application performance , any idea to solve that error .**

any explanation will be highly appreciated , thanks.

**the code of my project :**

**Menu :**

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "Introduction", "DreamsTrip", "Day one", "Day Two",
            "Day Three", "Day Four", "Day Five", "Conclusion" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // create background for whole list as image
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
        lv.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
        lv.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
        lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background);
        lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x00000000));
        setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {
            Intent ourIntent;
            if (position > 1 && position < 25) {
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.demo.MyDay");
                ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
                ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", cheese);
            } else {
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.demo." + cheese);
                ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            }
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {

            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                    AttributeSet attrs) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                    try {
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border3);
                                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(25);
                                ((TextView) view).setTypeface(FontFactory
                                        .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.test.demo.ABOUT");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.preferences:
            Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.PREFS");
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**MyArrayAdapter:**

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] classes;
    Typeface tf;

    static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] classes) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, classes);
        this.context = context;
        this.classes = classes;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_label);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
            viewHolder.text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getContext()));
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = classes[position];
        holder.text.setText(s);
        if (s.equals("Day one")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day1);
        }
        if (s.equals("Day Two")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day2);
        }
        if (s.equals("Day Three")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day3);
        }
        if (s.equals("Day Four")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day4);
        }
        if (s.equals("Day Five")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day5);
        }
        if (s.equals("Conclusion")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_concl);
        }
        if (s.equals("DreamsTrip")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_trip);
        }
        if (s.equals("Introduction")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_intr);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**MyDay:**

```
public class MyDay extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    TextView tv2, tv3, tv4;
    String day;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.day);
        if (customTitleSupported) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                    R.layout.custom_title);
        }
        initializeTextViews();
    }

    private void initializeTextViews() {
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day_tv1);
        tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day_tv3);
        tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getDroidNaskh(getBaseContext()));
        day = getIntent().getStringExtra("cheese");
        if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day One")) {
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
            tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day1)));
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                            R.style.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    text.setText(Html
                            .fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)));
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
                    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory
                            .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        } else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day Two")) {
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
            tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day2)));
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                            R.style.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    text.setText(Html
                            .fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_2)));
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
                    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory
                            .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        } else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day Three")) {
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
            tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day3)));
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                            R.style.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    text.setText(Html
                            .fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_3)));
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
                    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory
                            .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        } else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day Four")) {
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
            tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day4)));
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                            R.style.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    text.setText(Html
                            .fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_4)));
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
                    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory
                            .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        } else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day Five")) {
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
            tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day5)));
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
                            R.style.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); // set the
                    // custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    text.setText(Html
                            .fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_5)));
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
                    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory
                            .getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void handleClick(View v) {
        // Create an intent to start the new activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, DayGallery.class);
        intent.putExtra("dayname", day);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**logcat:**

```
D/AbsListView(14159): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 9% free 12164K/13315K, paused 13ms, total  
13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(14159): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.306MB for 1555216-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 8% free 13681K/14855K, paused 12ms+1ms, 
total 20ms
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 13681K/14855K, paused 10ms, total 
10ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(14159): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.941MB for 2764816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 16381K/17607K, paused 12ms+2ms, 
total 23ms
D/libEGL(14159): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
D/libEGL(14159): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
D/libEGL(14159): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
D/(14159): Device driver API match
D/(14159): Device driver API version: 10
D/(14159): User space API version: 10 
D/(14159): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
D/OpenGLRenderer(14159): Enabling debug mode 0
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1732K, 16% free 15672K/18439K, paused 19ms, 
total 19ms
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
D/dalvikvm(14159): GC_CONCURRENT freed 691K, 13% free 16102K/18439K, paused 13ms+2ms, 
total 27ms
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
W/OpenGLRenderer(14159): Shape round rect too large to be rendered into a texture 
(680x12472, max=4096x4096)
W/OpenGLRenderer(14159): Shape round rect too large to be rendered into a texture 
(688x12480, max=4096x4096)
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(14159): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
length
```

Comment: Have you checked that all references to the package in the new project are in fact referencing the new package name and not the old package name? Also, would you be able to post some of your listactivity that is causing the problem?

Comment: @TronicZomB both backage name is the same old one and new one

Comment: Ok, I kinda figured otherwise you would have other errors I'm sure.

Comment: @TronicZomB and logcat show just one red line error without spacify which activity happen on it as : SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: I do not understand -"and now tested on both ginger bread and jelly bean work perfectly" - you mean you tested `aap_one` and does not have the problem with menu ? And `app_one` and the new one _ONLY differ in name ?_ Before the **Update** which app were you talking about ????

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D i update my question , please check it , thanks

Comment: Is the name change genuinely _the only change_ between the two packages?

Comment: @NeilTownsend yes only app name

Comment: Can you test the old app (before name change) on the device that is giving the error now? - ie test the old app today, on the error giving device? Does it still work perfectly?

Comment: Have you tried the inputType suggestion?

Comment: So of course the 2 apps were different - not only in name. Alright - in the logs - which process is 13586 (or 6913) ? Are you sure they are your processes ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D my friend after that happened with me i checked each line in both projects accurately just application name and this line :android:textIsSelectable="true" is the difference,second point ( which process is 13586 (or 6913) , how to know this my friend ,thanks

Comment: second point -: google it and answer _me_ - if I have to answer all small things how can I answer real question ?- Find the processes - it might be another process that creates the warning. Also post your code for creating these rows

Comment: @AndroidStack, you can isolate the `LogCat` messages in DDMS. In Eclipse, open the DDMS perspective and choose the `LogCat` tab. On the right is the Messages section, on the left is the Filters section.  Choose the green plus sign in the Filters section.  Enter "MyApp" for "Filter Name" and enter the full package name in the "by Application Name" field.  Leave the rest blank.  This will isolate massages coming from your App.

Comment: @AndroidStack, Please post the method you use for registering the onClick event (e.g., `onListItemClick`).  The one you posted above does not suffice, as it is not the Application that you're having the problem with.  Don't try to duplicate your error in another program.

Answer (score 4):

To understand what is happening here, it all starts with a design decision about what a `TextView` should and shouldn't be. According to [the android source for TextView](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java):

```
/**
 * Displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it.  A TextView
 * is a complete text editor, however the basic class is configured to not
 * allow editing; see {@link EditText} for a subclass that configures the text
 * view for editing.
```

This means that, even if all you're doing is putting a piece of text on the screen, hidden behind that are full text highlight, selection and editing facilities. What has happened here is that a little tweak to resolve an issue in them appears to have interfered with some other functionality, and created some log lines. That this is the case is given more weight by, say, [Nexus 7 error "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488695/nexus-7-error-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length?rq=1), in which it would seem that on some android versions this situation can be resolved by disabling autocomplete in text (entry) fields:

```
View.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS );
```

This could also be done in the XML using the corresponding tags for a `TextView`:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

The lines in question appear to have arrived in Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean), in the `setSpan` function of `SpannableStringBuilder` (eg. [2.2.3 source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/2.2.3/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java) vs [4.1.1 source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java)). The log line is triggered by an attempt to set a span within a string of zero length. This is why setting it so that no (sub) section of the text needs to be selected should avoid this error, either by the above tip or by using:

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:editable="false"
```

A more speculative solution maybe to ensure that there is never a blank string in a `TextView` by adding the character "\u200b" (a non-shown blank character of zero width) to every string you put in your `TextView`s, either by overriding `setText` (to simply add it to the end of the string) in a custom `TextView` or by putting it in your code for every string sent to `TextView`s.

For those who like delving into the android system and overriding parts of it, according to [this piece of android source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Editable.java) it looks like it mght be possible to solve the issue by the following. However, there is absolutely no guarantee that it works. The truly brave (foolhardy) can write a complete SpannableStringBuilder for themselves ....

1. Creating your own form of `SpannableStringBuilder` which traps the condition. This example simply stops quietly, rather than stopping loudly, as per the original:

   ```
   import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;

   public class MySpannableStringBuilder extends SpannableStringBuilder {
       // Taken from SpannableStringBuilder.java
       private static final int MARK = 1;
       private static final int POINT = 2;
       private static final int START_MASK = 0xF0;
       private static final int END_MASK = 0x0F;
       private static final int START_SHIFT = 4;

       MySpannableStringBuilder() {
           super();
       }

       MySpannableStringBuilder(CharSequence text) {
           super(text);
       }

       MySpannableStringBuilder(CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
           super(text, start, end);
       }

       @Override
       public void setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags) {
           // Determine if the error is going to be triggered, if so fail silently
           int flagsStart = (flags & START_MASK) >> START_SHIFT;
           int flagsEnd = flags & END_MASK;
           if (flagsStart == POINT && flagsEnd == MARK && start == end) {
               return;
           }

           // All good, so call the real routine
           super.setSpan(what, flagsStart, end, flagsEnd);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Creating `MyEditableFactory extends Editable.Factory` and setting it to return your SpannableStringBuilder:

   ```
   import android.text.Editable;

   public class MyEditableFactory extends Editable.Factory {
       private static MyEditableFactory sInstance = new MyEditableFactory();

       /**
         * Returns this Editable Factory.
         */
       public static Editable.Factory getInstance() {
           return sInstance;
       }

       public Editable newEditable(CharSequence source) {
           return new MySpannableStringBuilder(source);
       }
   }
   ```

Other than writing a custom version of the OS and putting it on the phone, I'm not sure what else is possible.

All suggestions for improvement welcome, as well as feedback on using this code in various OS situations.

Comment: both applications (trip and travel) have exactly the same construction and the same package name . and tested in the same devices , but old one works ok and new one had error with jelly bean device ( the same device run old one ok )

Comment: What are the strings you are putting in the textviews and other places text may be displayed. Is it possible that some are empty, or even just have spaces in them?

Comment: i will check it my dear when i reach home

Comment: yes i try it. Another thing i test another apps it gave same error , once app include Textview ,that error rised in logcat

Comment: @SohamChowdhury would you be able to clarify what should be refactored to what please? If there's a simple answer I'd love to know it, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Which keyboard are you using for the textview? For some keyboards (which are not the native Andorid) you may face this problem.

See: http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/2994580-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-

Comment: im using native android keyboard

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may not be able to parse/use the Arabic (correct me if I'm wrong) text.

You can try by explicitly setting each `String` under `UTF-8`:

```
String[] classes = 
    {
        new String("example1".getBytes(), "UTF-8"),
        new String("example2".getBytes(), "UTF-8")
    };
```

Do the same for the calls to `equals` in the `onListItemClick`

```
String cheese = new String(classes[position].getBytes(), "UTF-8");

    if(cheese.equals(new String("المقدمة".getBytes(), "UTF-8")))
    {
        cheese = new String("Introduction".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    }
```

Better yet, just make a method.

```
private Object stringUTF8(final Object string)
{
    try
    {
        return new String(((String) string).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: its not the matter of arabic , i did same app totally english with same constructor but the same error in log cat , i will post it withen 5 minutes better not to be confused with arabic language on app , thanks

Comment: please check UPDAT 5 THANKS